# setValues doesn't iterate through the arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google-apps script for Spreadsheet

I have an Object array of variable length. `[{}, {}]`
I use for loop`(i=0; i<Obj.length; i++)` to iterate through each Object item and get the values off the keys with another for loop`(var p in Obj[i])` for Object.
This then gets pushed to an empty array - `row =[]` - which gets populated with iterated values `Obj[i][p]`.

When it jumps over to next `Obj[i]`, the row array should be pushed to the google sheet and then empty itself with - `row = []` initialization - then iterate over next `Obj[i]`.

Logger.log fantastically logs as expected:

```
[16-01-18 07:39:56:418 AEDT] [4 secs, , Mailbox, 7:05:47 AM, finished,     7:05:51 AM, 2016-01-17T20:05:47.142Z, 2016-01-17T20:05:51.891Z, MAILBOX]
[16-01-18 07:39:56:419 AEDT] []
[16-01-18 07:39:56:420 AEDT] pushed
[16-01-18 07:39:56:420 AEDT] [5 secs, , Adhoc, 7:05:51 AM, finished, 7:05:56 AM, 2016-01-17T20:05:51.892Z, 2016-01-17T20:05:56.896Z, ADHOC TASKS]
[16-01-18 07:39:56:421 AEDT] []
[16-01-18 07:39:56:422 AEDT] pushed
[16-01-18 07:39:56:422 AEDT] [3 secs, , Huddle, 7:05:56 AM, finished, 7:06:00 AM, 2016-01-17T20:05:56.897Z, 2016-01-17T20:06:00.187Z, HUDDLE]
[16-01-18 07:39:56:423 AEDT] []
[16-01-18 07:39:56:424 AEDT] pushed
[16-01-18 07:39:56:424 AEDT] [13 mins 3 secs, , Audits, 7:06:00 AM, finished, 7:19:03 AM, 2016-01-17T20:06:00.189Z, 2016-01-17T20:19:03.384Z, AUDITS]
[16-01-18 07:39:56:426 AEDT] []
[16-01-18 07:39:56:426 AEDT] pushed
```

However in the sheet, it logs only the last pushed row array and that too twice all the time, except if the main Obj array only has one Object item in it.

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
function getThisToTrix(Obj) {
  //  Logger.log(Obj);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("_id"),
  sheetName="abc",
  sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName),
  col = [], row = [],
  headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0], 
  nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1
  ;

  for(var i = 0; i<Obj.length; i++){
    for(var p in Obj[i]){
      col.push(p);
      row.push(Obj[i][p]);
    }

   Logger.log(row);
   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

   row=[];
   Logger.log(row);
   pushed();
  }
}

function pushed(){Logger.log("pushed");}
```

UPDATE:
Execution Transcript:

```
[16-01-23 00:20:46:140 HKT] Sheet.getLastColumn() [0.02 seconds]
[16-01-23 00:20:46:141 HKT] Sheet.getRange([1, 1, 1, 9]) [0 seconds]
[16-01-23 00:20:46:165 HKT] Range.getValues() [0.023 seconds]
[16-01-23 00:20:46:263 HKT] Sheet.getLastRow() [0.097 seconds]
[16-01-23 00:20:46:264 HKT] Sheet.getRange([88, 1, 3, 9]) [0 seconds]
[16-01-23 00:20:46:265 HKT] Range.setValues([[[987 ms, , Mailbox, 12:20:38 AM, finished, 12:20:39 AM, 2016-01-22T16:20:38.351Z, 2016-01-22T16:20:39.338Z, MAILBOX], [862 ms, , Audits, 12:20:39 AM, finished, 12:20:40 AM, 2016-01-22T16:20:39.352...) [0 seconds]
[16-01-23 00:20:46:458 HKT] Execution succeeded [0.243 seconds total  runtime]
```

Comment: Generally you should build your 2D array first and then call `setValues` only one time with all of your data rather than inside a for loop

Comment: @User was thinking of that if I wasn't able to figure out the problem. Just to be sure, to do that, we need to do another loop on the array created with `headers.length` as number of columns and jump to next row?

Comment: In the output do you want one object per row with the properties as columns?

Comment: yup, exactly what most of us working with the sheets do.

Answer (score 1):

`nextRow` never gets updated in your `for` loop, does it?  So you keep altering the same row in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yeah figured that one out myself. Lots of bugs around were already giving me hard time to figure this one out earlier.
Checked in the Execution Transcript to see it was calling in the same row in `getRange`. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your question is really how to convert the object array to the proper 2D array to pass to `setValues`.

I would structure it more like this:

```
function convertToArray(objectArray) {

  var result = [];

  for(var o in objectArray){
    var row = [];
    for(var property in objectArray[o]){
      row.push(objectArray[o][property]);
    }
    result.push(row);
  }

  return result;

}
```

And then:

```
var data = convertToArray(Obj);
sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length, numberOfColumns).setValues(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However in the `sheet.getRange(**1**, 1, data.length, numberOfColumns).setValues(data)` , that row number isn't ideal. We want to get last row before we push the data.
But using `lastRow()` and passing that parameter in row number always prints the data twice. I have no idea why. Execution Transcript shows once but in the sheet it's printing out twice.

But if I use static number like 1 then it prints only once. Any ideas? No change in code except for bringing in `lastRow()` value in row number value.

Comment: @СхирисхШреста: would need to see the full code to understand what's happening.  You could add it to http://pastebin.com/ and then put the link here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/K7R4cnqa

Looking at Execution Transcript of apps script, it seems that it prints data once, then takes nextRow value and then prints the data into the sheet again.

Comment: @СхирисхШреста: I don't see anything wrong but obviously you have more code that we can't see.  One thing is you should avoid all global variables unless absolutely necessary.  They can create subtle bugs.  Unless you need them elsewhere you should put your `doc`,`headers`, `nextRow` variables etc inside `getThisToTrix()` function.

Comment: I have other codes too but it's not related to this except `getUser` function which simply gets email address for sheet name.
If you look at the Update section above I posted, Execution Transcript says it gets `Sheet.getRange([88, 1, 3, 9]) [0 seconds]` but what happens in sheet is, it already prints the array from 85 to 87 _then_ gets 88 and prints it out again.

Comment: Similar problem I was having in https://repl.it/BfK0/3, the var diff there gets a numerical value, but in the `pst` statement, the variable would give an error. I was stomped left it like that w/o any edits few days ago, opened that document today just to tell u an example now it works fine.
in that problem if I would put a numerical value like -11 or -19 then pst would work but if passed diff ( which when console logged gives me correct number) would parse as an error in `pst` statement at the end.

Comment: @СхирисхШреста: As I said I would get rid of all global variables and also declare your variables as separate `var` statements for each one (this is more maintainable).  Then step through the debugger and see what's happening with the values.

Comment: scoping the variable didn't help either. I highly doubt it's related to that but Thanks!
As a work around, I created another function to remove the duplicates...a bit chunky but until I find the cause, gotta make it presentable.

Comment: @СхирисхШреста did you step through each line on the debugger? I would check either the contents of `Obj`, `data` or see if `setValues` is called more than once.  Also is this deployed as a Web App? If so, make sure you're using the correction version of the code.

Comment: haven't used apps script before so debugging seems to be cumbersome. I'm using HTMLService web app. From HTMLService's client side JS, I'm passing in the object array to `getThisToTrix` function. I put a breakpoint and turn on debugging mode.
Running just that function in debug mode will produce undefined since nothing's been passed through as `Obj`. And when I pass the `Obj` from web app, the debug mode won't trigger.
Kind of lost. Although, I've always managed to solve problems myself hitherto, for this once I'm tempted to pass on the copy of the project to you to have a look.

Comment: Jubilation! I figured it without the help of debugger or anything else! Started contemplating on what you said and checking on those Objects. It turns out that I do not know how to implement `withSuccessHandler()` and `withFailureHandler` properly. From client side JS, I had two lines of codes - one with each Handler calling the same `getThisToTrix` (thought it should be like that as it's documented).
I'm not used to chaining and didn't know one line of chaining was enough.

Anyways, finally after a week of suffering! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Checked the Execution Transcript to find out `getRange` was calling same row. Bit silly. This ended up looking like some panic callout for help. *smh

```
function getThisToTrix(Obj) {
  //  Logger.log(Obj);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("_id"),
  sheetName="abc",
  sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName),
  col = [], row = [],
  headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0], 
  nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1
  ;

  for(var i = 0; i<Obj.length; i++){
    for(var p in Obj[i]){
      col.push(p);
      row.push(Obj[i][p]);
    }

   Logger.log(row);
   sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
   nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;   //Answer to this.

   row=[];
   Logger.log(row);
   pushed();
  }
}

function pushed(){Logger.log("pushed");}
```

But still not sure why it would log twice all the time though instead of just once since it was calling in same Row number each time. Anyways, not my concern anymore.